# nhibernate custom collection mapping

Tags: nhibernate, mapping

How can I map a collection property of a concrete class, not an interface?
It's got to be concrete class! I have no control over the class I want to map, so I can't change to interface.

Right now I'm trying to solve this by writing a custom `IUserCollectionType` implementation and a custom `IPersistentCollection` implementation.

But... The following exception has stopped mu progress:

```
Test method ShouldSaveEntityWithSections threw exception: 
NHibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update;  actual row count: 0; expected: 1
```

Profiler shows that NHibernate doesn't try to insert related entity into the database, but tries to update it's foreign key to parent object.

The mapping is like this:

```
<set name="Rows" table="Rows" lazy="false" cascade="all"
     collection-type="My.PersistentListType`1[Blabla.Row, Blabla], My">
  <key column="ParentID" not-null="true" />
  <one-to-many class="Blabla.Row, Blabla" />
</set>
```

What's going on? Why doesn't NHibernate insert child entities into db?

Comment: can you show us the IUserCollectionType and IPersistentCollection implementation? it's likely that there is Problem in there

Comment: No, problem was in the test. Collection element type (`Blabla.Row` in my example) doesn't have default constructor. Instead it has the one which accept several parameters one of which is `Guid` that is to be used as primary key value. I mistakenly passed `Guid.NewGuid()` as a value that result in NHibernate thinking that the object is already persisted.

Comment: consider to post that as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. Hope it will help someone, who experience same problem.

That person should check that he\she doesn't create a related object in a state, which results in NHibernate thinking that it's already persisted.

In my case I mistakenly set a property mapped as primary key to `Guid.NewGuid()` instead of `Guid.Empty`.